# NLog for running multiple same aplication

Tags: c#-4.0, nlog

Need help, just wondering how to use NLog file and start multiple same application on same time.

So, if I running with application 1 create NLog_1.txt, application 2 create NLog_2.txt, etc... the NLog always create sequence for application is start.

For all this time just one application one NLog file

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer, so I use `${processid}` on NLog config file it will create different proccess id per application.

Thank you